# Contradiction in function of $e^{\frac {-1}{x^2}}$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x \to 0}  e^{-1/x^2} =0$$

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}  e^{-1/x^2} =1$$

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty}  e^{-1/x^2} =1$$

But derivative of $e^{-1/x^2}$ when $x<0$ is less than zero that means the function should decrease when $x<0$ but as $x$ tends to minus infinity it goes to $1$ that means it is a contradiction.

Comment: Well, sure, if you travel down a hill when going east, then you will go up a hill when going west. $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x)$ is going left in the real line. You could make the same argument about the function $x^2$ - since $\lim_{x\to-\infty} x^2=+\infty$.

Comment: $f(-\infty)=1$ and $f(0)=0$. Decreasing means, as $x$ gets bigger, $f(x)$ gets smaller. So this is consistent with the derivative being less then zero.

Comment: Why do you think that the limit 1 for $x\rightarrow -\infty$ contradicts the fact that the function is decreasing for $x<0$?. Actually it is perferctly decreasing 

$$f(-\infty)= 1,\;f(-5)\approx 0.96,\;f(-2)\approx 0.78,\;f(-1)\approx 0.37 \dots$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No contracdiction. The function is indeed decreasing for $x < 0$:

[image]

Comment: I really don't get why someone downvoted this one.

Comment: @Tom-Tom I was puzzled too